# Java 8 - remove items of list in list

Tags: java-8

I have this lists in lists:

```
List<List<ScheduleContainer>> scheduleIntervalContainersOfWeek
```

and my aim is to have this list

```
List <List<ScheduleContainer>> scheduleIntervalContainersOfWeek
```

with ScheduleIntervalContainers where interspace is null oder false.

Therefore I will first convert all ScheduleContainers into ScheduleIntervalContainer (ScheduleContainer is base class of SchedueIntervalContainer) and then I will remove all ScheduleIntervalContainer where field **interspace** of ScheduleIntervalContainer is true.

I have tried it with:

```
scheduleIntervalContainersOfWeek.stream().filter(...)
```

but I don't know the lambda expression in filter method.

Currently I have solved this problem like this:

```
for (final List<ScheduleContainer> scheduleContainers : scheduleIntervalContainersOfWeek) {
        for (final ScheduleContainer scheduleContainer : scheduleContainers) {

            final ScheduleIntervalContainer scheduleIntervalContainer = (ScheduleIntervalContainer)scheduleContainer;

            // if sic is absence container than continue (absence sics are shown in schedule)
            if (scheduleIntervalContainer.getInterspace()) {
                continue;
            }
```

Comment: This is a bit unclear. Can you provide a sample input / output, along with the code of the classes you're working with?

Comment: This was my approach: **scheduleIntervalContainersOfWeek.stream().forEach(s -> s.stream().map(p -> (ScheduleIntervalContainer)p).filter(r -> (r.getInterspace() == null || r.getInterspace() == false)));** I only need the ScheduleIntervalContainer where **r.getInterspace() == null || r.getInterspace() == false**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
scheduleContainers = scheduleContainers.stream()
  .filter(sc -> !Boolean.TRUE.equals(((ScheduleIntervalContainer)sc).getInterspace()))
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Note the use of a [Yoda condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions) to avoid the need for a null check.